# The Guardian style animated graphic novel

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Do you have an idea of how is this done?
http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2012/nov/06/america-elect-graphic-novel

UPDATE:

Sorry to not to be so clear.

OF COURSE, I did check out the source code of this site. I knew that animation is about CSS or jQuery or HTML5...

But I wasn't sure about which plug-in or technic is used here on this site.

This was the question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source and figuring it out?

Comment: `scrollTop` => animation time. Draw the frame that's defined by the scroll position whenever the scroll position changes. That's what I would do. I doubt there's any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the famous [Parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) effect. Essentially it's achieved by manipulating z-index from images over the background while scrolling.

There are some jQuery plugins with the objective of achieve such effect in a fancy and easy way. When the [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com) site comes back to life you could make a [search](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-parallax-style) for such plugin.

As stated by @devdigital however, they are using [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/) in their site.

From the github page, skrollr is describe as:

> Stand-alone parallax scrolling lib for mobile (Android + iPhone) and desktop

or in a more exaggerated perspective:

> Actually, skrollr is much more than "just" parallax scrolling. It's a full-fledged scrolling animation library. In fact, you can use it and still have no parallax scrolling at all. But I wanted to sound hip and use some buzz-words. By the way, skrollr leverages HTML5 and CSS3

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question without any attacking just like some people did above...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source, they're using skrollr - http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/

Comment: TIL about this plugin. It looks cool and useful if used properly.